# Let $ k $ belong to the naturals. Prove that $3k^2+2$ is never a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm been struggling with this proof for a couple of hours. I originally thought I could prove it by contradiction and let some $n^2=3k^2+2 $to prove there is a contradiction, but it got me nowhere. Any hints?

Comment: As a follow up to @RossMillikan's very good hint: consider what you get from $(3k)^2\pmod 3$, $(3k+1)^2\pmod 3$ and $(3k+2)^2\pmod 3$.

Comment: [Extremely similar question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692014/prove-that-3a2-1-is-never-a-perfect-square-when-a-is-an-integer?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider your equation $\pmod 3$

Answer (score 3):

If exist $n$ integer such as $3k^2=n^2-2$

then $3|(n^2-2)$

that is $n^2\equiv2$ (mod 3).

But the last congruence has no solutions because the only squares (mod 3) are 1 and 0.

Comment: Nice first post!