# Proving, by contradiction, that there are infinitely $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational.

Tags: proof-verification

I would like to know whether I have proved this statement correctly using contradiction and if not get some tips or pointers on how to improve it/make it correct.

We are asked to prove  that there are infinitely $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that  $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational.

Proof: $$\text{We assume, to the contrary, that there are infinitely many } n \text{ } (n \in Z^+) \text{ such that } \sqrt{n} \text{ is rational.} \\\text{Then, } \sqrt{n}=\frac{a}{b} \text{,  } n=\frac{a^2}{b^2}  \text{ where } a \text{ and } b \text{ are integers and } \frac{a}{b} \text{ has been reduced to lowest terms.} \\\text{Hence, } a^2=nb^2 \text{ and } b^2=\frac{1}{n}a^2\\\text{We know if } n\mid a^2 \text{ then } n\mid a \text{. It follows that } a=nk, k\in\mathbb{Z} \\ b^2=\frac{1}{n}(nk)^2=nk^2 \text{ and thus } n\mid b^2 \text{ and thus } n \mid b \\
\text{Hence, } n = \frac{nb^2}{nk^2} \\
\text{This is a contradiction given that we have assumed }a \text{ and } b \text{ to be reduced to lowest terms. }\blacksquare$$  ps. This isn't homework. Answers are in the back of my book but I want to improve.

Comment: No, your first statement is wrong. Your first statement should be "we assume to the contrary that there are **finitely** many natural numbers $n$ such that $\sqrt{n}$ is **irrational**".

Comment: Also, $n|a^2$ does not in general imply $n|a$. Counterexample: $n=4,\,a=2$.

Comment: @stressedout Can you elaborate on how to correctly identify the hypothesis and conclusion in this statement? I have a hard time doing this when the statement isn't in the form of if ..., then ...

Comment: For completeness regarding what @J.G. said, in the other direction, it is (trivially) true: If $n|a$ then $n|a^2$

Comment: The best way to negate a statement is to ask yourself when it's false? If I claim that something holds for an infinite number of things and I want to disprove it, I should show that only a finite number of things with that property can exist. Right? Now look at the flaw of your negation: We know that there exists an infinite number of *odd* integers. But we also know that there exists an infinite number of *even* integers! Do you see the problem with your negation now?

Comment: Why don't you use a direct proof ? You can for example use the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ to easily show the irrationality of every number $\sqrt{2k^2}=k\sqrt{2}$ where $k$ is a positive integer immediately proving the given statement.

Comment: @stressedout Ah, yes thank you! That's obvious.. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Peter My book asked me to prove it via contradiction rather than by direct proof.

Comment: Well, Peter's argument can be modified to a proof by contradiction. A valid proof can assume that only a finite number of something with property blah blah can exist and then shows that you can always find a new thing satisfying your conditions that isn't in your list!

Comment: @Cro-Magnon If you show that $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational if and only if $n$ is not a perfect square the given statement becomes equivalent to "There are infinite many positive integers that are not a perfect square". So you only have to refute that there are only finite many positive integers that are not a perfect square.

Comment: @Peter I see. This really helped me. I'm going to ponder this for a while and redo the proof. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the statement you are trying to prove, saying? It is saying that the number of elements of the set $\{n \in \mathbb N : \sqrt n \ \mbox{is irrational}\}$, is infinite.

What is the opposite of this statement? Naturally, that the number of elements of that set is *not* infinite, in which case it is finite. So, the contradictory statement is this :

> The set $\{n \in \mathbb N : \sqrt n \ \mbox{ is irrational}\}$ is finite. Or, there are only finitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $\sqrt n$ is irrational.

Now, you have to assume this is true, and derive a contradiction.

---

To derive a contradiction to this statement, you have to realize, that every *non-empty* finite set of natural numbers has a *maximum* element. We know, from a classical proof by contradiction, that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational, so $2$ is an element of our subject set.

So, if the set of natural numbers $n$ such that $\sqrt n$ is irrational has a maximum, then let $L$ be that maximum number. So $\sqrt L$ is irrational.

But, as Peter mentioned in his comment, $2 \sqrt L$ is also irrational, and this is equal to $\sqrt{4L}$, so $4L$ also belongs to the set of natural numbers whose square roots are irrational... can you take it from here?

---

Note that Peter's comment may also be used to produce infinitely many members of the set, so the two arguments , contradiction and direct proof, are not very different from one another.

Comment: Of course, phrasing this as a proof by contradiction is an enormous obfuscation of what you're doing. You're just directly constructing an infinite sequence of integers with no rational square root.

Answer (score 1):

An idea for a different kind of proof:

It is known that $\sqrt{n}$ rational if and only if $n$ is a perfect square.

Indeed, assume that  $\sqrt{n} = \frac{a}{b}$ with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. Hence there exist $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\alpha a - \beta b = 1$.

Now $$0 = (a-b\sqrt{n})(\beta + \alpha \sqrt{n}) = \beta a - \alpha bn + (\alpha a - \beta b) \sqrt{n} = \beta a - \alpha bn + \sqrt{n}$$

And hence $\sqrt{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$ so $n$ is a perfect square. The converse is obvious.

Now it just remains to show that the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N} : n \text{ is not a perfect square}\}$ is infinite.

For this notice that numbers of the form [$3k^2+2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1149985/144766) for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ are never perfect squares.