# Square roots proved irrational by denominator descent

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, rationality-testing

> Is this proof correct?

Suppose that $\sqrt{2}=\dfrac{a}{b}$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a$ is as small as possible. Then $\sqrt{2}b=a$ which means $2b=\sqrt{2} a$. So we rewrite $\sqrt{2}=\dfrac{a}{b}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}-1}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}a-a}{\sqrt{2}b-b}=\dfrac{2b-a}{a-b}.\,$ Note  $\,2b-a=a\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)\lt a$. So this fraction has a smaller numerator than the one we had. So this is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, this is a well-known proof.

Comment: @user42493 This is essentially the same as [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent#Irrationality_of_%E2%88%9Ak_if_it_is_not_an_integer) with $a=m$, $b=n$, $k=2$, $q=1$. At least you were creative enough to 'discover' another proof.

Comment: Note that $2b-a<a$ is equivalent to $2b<2a$, which is true because $a>b$.

Comment: For the proof to be complete you should verify that $2b-a$ and $a-b$ are natural numbers. They are obviously integers, but why are they positive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the proof is correct. It is a well-known  proof, essentially using **denominator descent** using the division algorithm, though that is *greatly obfuscated*. Below I clarify this viewpoint for the generalization below (the OP proof is *exactly* the special case $\, k = 2\,$ and $\,q = \lfloor \sqrt 2\rfloor = 1)$.

> **Irrationality of $\sqrt k\,$ if it is not an integer**  (excerpted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent#Irrationality_of_%E2%88%9Ak_if_it_is_not_an_integer), slightly edited)
>
> For an integer $k>0$, suppose $\sqrt k$ is not an integer, but is rational, so $\,\color{#c00}{\sqrt k = \frac{a}b}$ for naturals $a$ and $b.\,$ Let $\color{#0af}{q =\lfloor \sqrt k\rfloor} $ be the largest integer no greater than $\sqrt k.\,$ Then
>
> $$\begin{aligned}
> {\sqrt {k}}
> \,={\frac {a}{b}}&={\frac {a({\sqrt {k}}-q)}{b({\sqrt {k}}-q)}}\\[3pt]
> &={\frac {\color{#0a0f}a{\sqrt {k}}-aq}{b{\color{#c00}{\sqrt {k}}}-bq}}\\[3pt]
> &={\frac {\color{#0a0}{b{\sqrt {k}}}{\sqrt {k}}-aq}{\!\!b({\color{#c00}{{a}/{b}}})-bq}}\\[3pt]
> &={\frac {\color{#0a0}{bk-aq}}{\color{#c00}{a-bq}}}=\,\frac{a'}{b'}\end{aligned}\qquad$$
>
> The numerator and denominator were  multiplied by $\sqrt k − q\,$ which is $\rm\color{#0af}{{\rm positive\ and }< 1}$, yielding *integers* $a'$ and $b'$,  which are $\rm\color{#0af}{less}$ than $a$ and $b$ resp. Therefore, no matter what natural numbers $a$ and $b$ are used to express $\sqrt k$, there exist smaller natural numbers $a' < a$ and $b' < b$ that have the same ratio. But infinite descent on the natural numbers is impossible, so this disproves the original assumption that $\sqrt k$ could be expressed as a ratio of natural numbers.

We can rewrite the above proof much more *conceptually* as below, where "$n\,$ is a denom of $\,r$" means that the rational $\,r\,$ is writable with denominator $\,n,\,$ i.e. $\,n\,r = j\,$ for some integer $\,j.$

$$\begin{align}
[\![1]\!]\qquad\quad\:\!\ \  b \sqrt k\, &=\, a\qquad\ \, \Rightarrow \text{$\,b\ $ is a denom of }\:\! \sqrt k\\[.2em]
\sqrt k\,\cdot\, [\![1]\!]\ \ \, \Rightarrow\,[\![2]\!]\qquad\quad\ \   a\sqrt k\, &=\, bk\qquad  \Rightarrow \text{ $a\,$ is a denom of }\:\! \sqrt k\\[.2em]
[\![2]\!] - [\![1]\!]\:\!q\,\Rightarrow\,[\![3]\!]  \ \ \ \, (\color{#c00}{a\!-\!bq})\sqrt k\, &=\, \color{#0a0}{bk\!-\!aq}\,\Rightarrow\,  \color{#c00}{\bar a} \, \text{ is a denom of $\:\!\sqrt k,\,\ \color{#c00}{\bar a := a\bmod b}$}\\
\end{align}\quad$$

If  $\,b\,$ doesn't divide $\,a\,$ we get a *smaller* denom $\, 0 < \color{#c00}{a \bmod b} < b\,$ so infinite descent (on denoms), contra $\Bbb N\,$ is well-ordered. Hence $\,b\,$ divides $\,a,\,$ so $\,\sqrt k = a/b = n\in \Bbb Z,\,$ so  $\,k = n^2.\,$ $\bf\small QED$

---

Alternatively we can use the [minimal criminal form of descent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2948742/242): assume  $\,b\,$ is the *least* denom then deduce a contradiction that a smaller denom exists if $\,b\,$ does not divide $\,a$.

Or we can descend quicker via: $\,a,b$ denoms $\Rightarrow \gcd(a,b)\!=\!1$ is a denom. Or more simply (but slower) via: $\,a>b\,$ denoms $\Rightarrow a-b\,$ denom, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4585/242), along with generalizations.

Mod denominator descent ($a,b$ denoms $\Rightarrow a\bmod b\,$ denom) can also [be performed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16544/242) by taking fractional parts of equivalent fractions (a form popularized by John Conway).

**Generalization** $ $ The same method proves no proper fraction is a root of a polynomial that is monic (lead coef $= 1),\,$ i.e. the monic case of the [Rational Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/658006/242) (i.e.  $\,\Bbb Z\,$ [or any PID] is *integrally-closed*),  as I explain in a Remark [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39769/242). There is further discussion of this and related ideas in [various posts on **denominator ideals**](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+denominator+ideal).