# Gaps in Ireland & Rosen's proof of existence of prime factorizations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, induction, proof-explanation, integers

I'm new to number theory. This might be kind of a silly question, so I'm sorry if it is.

I encountered the classic lemma about every nonzero integer being the product of primes in Ireland and Rosen's textbook *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory*. In this textbook there is also a proof for it provided, and I'd like to understand why it is that the proof actually works.

The proof is as follows:

> Assume, for contradiction, that there is an integer $N$ that cannot be written as a product of primes. Let $N$ be the smallest positive integer with this property. Since $N$ cannot itself be prime we must have $N = mn$, where $1 < m, n < N$. However, since $m$, $n$ are positive and smaller than $N$ they must each be a product of primes. But then so is $N = mn$. This is a contradiction.

I feel like this proof kind of presupposes the lemma. I think this line of reasoning could be strengthened using induction, and I've seen other proofs of this lemma that use induction. Can someone help me out? What am I missing and why do I think that this proof of the lemma is circular?

**Edit:** I'd like to add that this textbook states that if $p$ is a prime number, then so is $-p$. That's where my confusion stems from.

Comment: That argument is by induction.  the result is easy to check for small numbers, so assume it holds up to $N-1$.  Then $N$ is either prime, in which case we are done, or it factors as $a\times b$ with $1<a≤b<N-1$ and you can apply the inductive hypothesis to $a,b$.  Same argument.

Comment: There is nothing missing in this proof. It is just fine. And why “two primes”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Typo. Fixed.

Comment: It's not circular, but it could be a lot clearer. It's not strictly necessary to say $n > 1$, since $m$ is positive and $mn$ is also positive.

Comment: It's a valid proof by **infinite descent** (a.k.a. **minimal criminal**), the contrapositive of induction - see the [Remark here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2948742/242). You should master both this (negative) and the normal (positive) form of induction.

Comment: $-1$ is an integer, and is not prime...

Comment: Please see [this](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/10034/1550) for a proper explanation of structural induction, which is relevant here. And note that the well-ordering principle for naturals (i.e. if some natural satisfies some property, then there is a least natural that satisfies that property) can be proven using induction (try it!) and is in fact equivalent to induction. You will see, however, that unlike structural induction the well-ordering principle is non-constructive in the sense that you don't see a top-down justification (you instead attack the least counter-example).

Comment: So structural induction is great if you want to 'see for yourself' that the claim 'really works' for any specific natural, following the structural induction proof itself. But the well-ordering principle has its own advantage: Many times you can easily find a contradiction from the least counter-example, and it might be super obvious that way but quite difficult to find the 'ordinary' induction proof. Examples include many combinatorial problems that fall easily to the [extremal principle](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Extreme_principle).

Comment: In each use of the extremal principle, induction is hiding in the fact that every finite list of real numbers has a minimum, which requires induction to prove. It's not a use of the well-ordering principle, but it has a similar flavour.

Comment: Notice that the statement "every nonzero integer can be written as a product of primes" is false. A counterexample is -15 which clearly is a non-zero integer, but there is no set of primes whose product is -15 (since every prime number is >= 2).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand According to the textbook, if p is a prime then -p is a prime :/

Comment: Genuine question: doesn't this rely on the definition of a prime, whose definition inherently answers the question?

Answer (score 22):

Although the proof by contradiction is correct, your feeling of unease is fine, because the direct proof by induction is so much clearer:

> Take an integer $N$. If $N$ is prime, there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, we must have $N = mn$, where $1 < m, n < N$. By induction, since $m, n$ are smaller than $N$, they must each be a product of primes. Then so is $N = mn$. Done.

Comment: This is equivalent, so how is it "so much clearer"? Personally, I find the original clearer.

Comment: @JohnColeman Also, the OP might be interested in how the infinite descent method has been 'pushed' in number theory. And Euclid had no problem with it! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent#Number_theory

Comment: @BobKrueger And I have seen so many unnecessary proofs by contradiction!

Comment: This too is **incorrect** since it doesn't handle the cases of negative integers, or $N = 1$, etc, which are some of the same problems as in the text. Of course they are easy to fix, but that's not the point. These points are explained at length in my answer. As such, this is not really an answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 12):

> I'm new to number theory. This might be kind of a silly question, so I'm sorry if it is.

No apology is necessary since your question is by no means silly. It is not at all surprising that you are puzzled by the cited exposition since it is incredibly sloppy. Kudos to you for reading it very carefully and noticing these problems.

> **Edit:** I'd like to add that this textbook states that if $p$ is a prime number, then so is $-p$. That's where my confusion stems from. The textbook is [*A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* by Ireland and Rosen](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-2103-4).

Let's examine closely that initial section on primes and prime factorizations.

On page $1$ begins a section titled "Unique Factorization in $\Bbb Z$" where they briefly review divisibility of "natural numbers $1,2,3\ldots"$ This leads to the following "definition" of a prime:

> Numbers that cannot be factored further are called primes. To be more precise, we say that a number $p$ is a prime if its only divisors are $1$ and $p.$

This is imprecise. Is $1$ a prime by this definition? In the next paragraph we find

> The first prime numbers are $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43,\ldots$

So $1$ is not prime. That agrees with modern conventions.

On the next page they segue into factorization in the ring of integers $\Bbb Z$ where they write

> If $p$ is a positive prime, $-p$ will also be a prime. We shall not consider $1$ or $-1$ as primes even though they fit the definition.

This poses a few problems. They now claim that $1$ *does* fit the prior definition of a prime, but they didn't list it above (or explain why it was excluded). Further it implies that  $ p = -2$ is a prime but it doesn't fit the above definition (it has divisors $\,\pm1, \pm 2,\,$ not only $1$ and $p$). They don't give any definition of a prime *integer* (vs. natural).

Readers familiar with basic ring theory and factorization in integral domains will likely have no problem inferring what is intended (the notion of an irreducible or indecomposable element), but any careful reader lacking such background will likely be quite puzzled by these inconsistencies and gaps.

As such, it comes as no surprise that the following proof (of *existence* of prime factorizations) employing these fuzzy notions may well prove troublesome for readers unfamiliar with the intended notions.

> **Lemma** $1.$ Every nonzero integer can be written as a product of primes.
>
> PROOF $ $ Assume that there is an integer that cannot be written as a product of
> primes. Let $N$ be the smallest positive integer with this property. Since $N$
> cannot itself be prime we must have $\,N = mn,\,$ where $1 < m,\, n < N.\,$ However, since $m$ and $n$ are positive and smaller than $N$ they must each be a
> product of primes. But then so is $N = mn.$ This is a contradiction.

The proof has many problems. It doesn't properly handle the (implied) prime factorization of $\pm1$ and they forgot to handle the possibility that the counterexample is negative (w.l.o.g. reducing to a positive counterexample).

Considering all of the above problems, it is no wonder that you found this proof  confusing.

> The proof can be given in a more positive way by using mathematical
> induction. It is enough to prove the result for all positive integers. $2$ is a
> prime. Suppose that $2 < N$ and that we have proved the result for all
> numbers $m$ such that $2 \leq m < N$. We wish to show that $N$ is a product of
> primes. If $N$ is a prime, there is nothing to do. If $N$ is not a prime, then
> $N = mn,$ where $2 \leq m,\, n < N.$ By induction both $m$ and $n$ are products of
> primes and thus so is $N.$

Here they've reformulated the induction from negative form - an [(infinite) *descent* on  counterexamples (or a "minimal criminal")](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2948742/242) - into a positive *ascent*, i.e. into a complete (or strong) induction, and they give some hint about the reduction to the positive case, but still there is no handling of $\pm1$. What is actually intended can be inferred  from  the next theorem they present.

> **Theorem** $1.$ For every nonzero integer $n$ there is a prime factorization
>
> $$   n\, =\ (-1)^{e(n)} \prod_p p^{a(p)}$$
>
> with the exponents uniquely determined by $n$. Here $e(n) = 0$ or $1$ depending on whether $n$ is positive or negative and where the product is over all positive primes. The exponents $a(p)$ are nonnegative integers and, of course, $a(p) = 0$ for all but finitely many primes.

That explains how they handle the prime factorization of $\pm1$ and the reduction to positive primes. With that in mind you should be able to fix the proof of the lemma.

As above, often when there is puzzling exposition in textbooks it can be clarified by reading a bit further to help infer what was intended. But - of course - that is no excuse for sloppy exposition.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3543271/242) for an abstraction of this type of (multiplicative) induction - which greatly clarifies how it works.

Comment: Prima facie, by examining the Q&A/comments here, and even before your answer, I knew that the book could be depended on one thing - that any reader would be forced to put in their own finishing touches to make the material  'crystallize '. . (+1) for providing a (partial) critical review of the book.

Comment: @CopyPasteIt It is a popular and widely-respected textbook.

Comment: Sure hope that knowing that prime numbers can be negative is used in later chapters. And that we all nod our heads and say  'what a modern and elegant approach'.

Comment: @CopyPasteIt When one studies factorization in more general rings (as in this textbook) the utility and naturality of such definitions becomes more apparent. In fact in some contexts it even proves convenient to use the convention that $-1$ is a prime, e.g. see John Conway's [eloquent arguments.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1175403/242)

Comment: Thanks for the link!  Without being up to speed on all the math there, 'it sounds right' that $-1$ can be considered a prime but not $1$. The number $1$ is just so special it can't be called anything else. Then come the positive primes in $\{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$. And then comes the amazing introduction of $-1$ by sentient beings! A prime concept indeed...

Comment: Lemma 1 holds fine for $n = 1$ (as it is an empty product), but it fails for all negative integers (since primes are positive).

Comment: I might have gone off the deep end! see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3163498/432081

Comment: @darijgrinberg But given the many questions here and on sci.math about empty sums and products, that too would require some explanation for beginners. Btw, why did you approve a [suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1176484) which atempted to change the proof of Lemma 1? (which I quoted verbatim from the textbbook)

Comment: Oh, that was my suggested edit (for some reason, the browser here loves to crash and log me out). I thought you were writing that proof, rather than quoting it from a textbook!

Comment: My personal view on empty sums and products (based on teaching combinatorics classes) is this: Yes, they can be confusing to beginners, but there is nothing gained by avoiding them; it's just kicking the can down the road. So your post, which does a good job explaining the "minimal counterexample" trick, is also a fitting place for "the talk" on empty products (a fairly short talk if one doesn't try to justify things too much).

Comment: @darij  I explicitly addressed the convenience of empty and singleton products for terminating multiplicative inductions  in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3543271/242).

Answer (score 10):

The proof is not circular, the key is in the second sentence: *Let N be the smallest positive integer with this property.*

We are allowed to say a least $N$ exists because of the [well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle).

Comment: I don't know if it's because of the well-ordering principle ... that's like using a hammer to slice through butter. One does not need the full strength of the AOC to prove such a simple statement.

Comment: @Don What's AOC? I presume you're not talking about Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez.

Comment: @RobertSoupe: Axiom of choice.  The more usual abbreviation is AC.

Comment: @DonThousand: I think "well-ordering principle" here refers to the statement "the usual ordering on the natural numbers is a well order".  The Axiom of Choice equivalent is "every set admits an ordering which is a well order" - that wouldn't really even help with this proof, since it would only tell us that there is *some* ordering of the natural numbers which is a well order - it doesn't tell us that the *usual* ordering is one.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Indeed, the well-ordering principle (*not* the similarly-named well-ordering theorem) is equivalent to induction (and probably also to infinite descent, but I haven't worked through that one yet), so if you disallow WOP, then you are going to have a hard time proving a lot of things.

Comment: @DonThousand - The Axiom of Choice is not necessary to prove that the natural numbers are well-ordered. These were known to be well-ordered long before the axiom of choice was even imagined.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I completely agree. My misunderstanding was the difference between WOP and WOT

Answer (score 5):

> I feel like this proof kind of presupposes the lemma.

Because it does.
It says so right in the first two sentences, which can be rephrased as:

> *Let $N$ be the smallest positive integer that cannot be written as a product of primes.*

So yes, the proof assumes that all positive integers *smaller* than $N$ **can** be written as a product of primes.
This is OK, though, because it is trivially true for the smallest integers: 1, 2. The proof builds on that to infer that no such an $N$ exists where the lemma is not true.

Answer (score 4):

I can definitely understand how this can feel a little off.

1) The lemma (as stated in the question) says all nonzero integers. Primes are integers and, by definition, cannot be products of primes. So, I think the lemma probably is actually more along the lines of: "all positive non-prime integers can be written as a product of primes".

2) Also, the statement "since , are positive and smaller than  they must each be a product of primes" doesn't really explain why they must be a product of primes. Since,  is the smallest positive non-prime integer that cannot be written as a product of primes (by supposition of the lemma), then , are either prime themselves or a product of primes (as they are less than  and  is the smallest number that isn't a product of primes). Either way, they will provide the primes necessary to create , making  able to be constructed as a product of primes.

Hopefully this helps to see why the proof by contradiction works.

Comment: As far as your (1) is concerned, I think this is just a matter of "over-mathematical" style in the question. 35 is a product of primes. It is a product of the _two_ primes 5 and 7. 37 is a product of primes. It is a product of the _one_ primes 37. But you have raised the extra, interesting point: the statement is "every non-zero integer" but the proof assumes integers >1. Which rather implies that 1 is either not an integer or not non-zero!

Comment: @MartinKochanski The standard way of dealing with $1$ is that the product of zero terms is $1$ by convention, so $1$ is the product of zero primes.

Answer (score 4):

An integer $n$ is said to be a *composite* if it can be expressed as the product of two integers $a$ and $b$ with $a \notin \{-1,0,1\}$ and $b \notin \{-1,0,1\}$.

An integers $p \notin \{-1,0,1\}$ that is not a composite is called a *prime number*.

Recall the [method of infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent) used in mathematical proofs.

Suppose $m \notin \{-1,0,1\}$ and it can't be expressed as a product of primes. If $m \lt 0$ then it is certainly true that the positive number $-m$ can't be factored into primes. So the existence of $m$ allows us to assert that there are positive integers greater than $1$ that can't be factored into a product of prime numbers.

So using infinite descent, we have a minimal $n > 1$ that can't be written as a product of primes. In particular, $n$ can't be a prime. But then it must be a composite, and we can write

$\quad n = st \text{ with } s,t \gt 1$

Note: The composite factors $s$ and $t$ must both be positive or negative.
If they are both negative, replace $s$ with $-s$ and $t$ with $-t$.

But then $s \lt n$ and so it can be written as a product of primes. Similarly, $t$ can be written as a product of primes. But then $n$ itself is a product of primes. But this is not possible by our choice of $n$. So the initial assumption of the existence of $m \notin \{-1,0,1\}$ with no prime factorization leads to a contradiction.

So every  $n \notin \{-1,0,1\}$ has a prime factorization.

Answer (score 2):

There is a property of the natural numbers called [well-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order). A set is well-ordered if every non-empty subset has a least element. So given any property $P$:

1. The set of numbers for which $P(n)$ is false is either empty or has a least element.
2. Suppose there is some number $n_0$ such that $P(n_0)$ is false. If $n_0$ is the least such number, then obviously $P(n_0-1)$ is true <sup>[1]</sup> (otherwise $n_0-1$ would be a number for which $P$ is false that is smaller than $n_0$, and so $n_0$ wouldn't be the smallest such number).
3. Thus, if we can prove that there is no number $n_0$ such that $P(n_0-1)$ is true and $P(n_0)$ is false (i.e. "$\neg \exists n_0: (P(n_0-1) \land \neg P(n_0))$", then we have shown that the set of numbers for which $P$ is false has no least element.
4. "$\neg \exists n_0: (P(n_0-1) \land \neg P(n_0))$" is equivalent to "$\forall n_0: (\neg P(n_0-1) \lor P(n_0))$", which is in turn equivalent to "$\forall n_0: (P(n_0-1) \rightarrow P(n_0))$".
5. Thus, if we can prove $\forall n_0: (P(n_0-1) \rightarrow P(n_0))$, then it follows that the set of numbers for which $P(n)$ is false does not have a least element. Since all non-empty sets of natural numbers have a least element, this set must be empty. That is, there are no numbers for which $P(n)$ is false, i.e. $P(n)$ is true for all $n$.

[1] There is also the possibility that $n_0-1$ isn't a natural number, which happens when $n_0=0$. Dealing with this possibility requires proving that $P(0)$ is true separately, which is why induction proofs require a base case.

So that's the concept behind induction proofs: if the proposition isn't true for all numbers, then there is a non-empty set of numbers for which it is false, which has to have a least element, which means that we have to go from "true" to "false" at some point. Inductive proofs thus look a bit like circular reasoning: you start assuming that the proposition is true, and use that to prove that the proposition is true. But what makes it non-fallacious is that you prove that the proposition is true for a *later* number by assuming that it's true for an *earlier* number.

The proof that you cite is using the same basic principle as induction, namely the well-order of the natural numbers, but it is skipping the one-by-one sort of process that induction proofs usually use. Instead of saying "If $P(n_0)$ is false, then $P(n_0-1)$ being true leads to a contradiction", it's saying "If $P(n_0)$ is false, then $P(n)$ being true for $n<n_0$ leads to a contradiction". Like a standard induction proof, it superficially looks like circular reasoning, but isn't, because it's proving that the proposition is true for $N$ using the fact that it's true for *smaller* numbers.