# Errors (?) in Ireland & Rosen

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The work referred to is Ireland and Rosen *A classical introduction to modern number theory*, GTM 84, 2nd ed.

On page 1 *prime* is defined as follows: a number $p$ is a prime if its only divisors are 1 and $p$. That makes 1 a prime which is surely not intended. On page 2, where primes in $\mathbb Z$ are discussed, I&R *do* exclude $\pm1$. On page 3 they claim *Every nonzero integer can be written as a product of primes*. I am prepared to believe that 1 is a product of primes, i.e., it is the product of the empty set (of primes), but I think $-1$ has to be excluded. I don't think I&R are simply being careless, so what am I missing?

Comment: This is indeed sloppy, as they should have said $p\geq 2$. They somewhat imply this in the next paragraph with "The first prime numbers are 2,3,5,..."

Comment: I think they are being careless, and I also think they are writing for a readership who already know very well what prime numbers are.

Comment: Leading up to that passage, they say, "If we are given a number, it is tempting to factor it again and again until further factorization is impossible. [...] Numbers that cannot be factored further are called primes." Okay, so $2 = 1 \times 2 = 1 \times 1 \times 2 = \ldots$, therefore $2$ is not a prime. They're simply being careless.

Comment: This imprecision has been noted here before at length, e.g.see [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3162536/242). If your question is answered there then let me know and I'll close this as a dupe. If not please clarify what remains unanswered.

Comment: @Gone - my question is certainly related to what you cite, and there is a good discussion there!  I have this worry: sloppiness on the first three pages I can recognize and fix for myself, but what if the sloppiness continues throughout the book?  But that's not a question for stack exchange, it's just a warning to myself. Do close my q. if you wish to.