# Request to check a proof for existence of prime decomposition of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, solution-verification

I wrote a proof by contradiction for the existence of a prime decomposition for all positive integers, I came up with it while I was trying solidify my understanding of the theorem itself. (Just existence, not uniqueness). If you are reading this and are interested, would you check for any errors? Thank you for reading!

-Proof-

Take $z\geq2\in\mathbb{Z}$ where z is not prime.

Then $$ \exists\;a_{01},a_{02}\geq2\;s.t.\;a_{01}a_{02}=z$$

If both factors are prime, than we are done.

If not, then $$\exists\;a_{11},a_{12}\geq2\;s.t. a_{11}a_{12}=a_{0i_{0}}$$ where $i_{0}=1$ or $2$

If $a_{11},a_{12}$ prime, we are done.

If one is not, then
$$ \exists a_{21}a_{22}\geq2\; s.t.\; a_{21}a_{22}=a_{1i_{1}}\; where\; i_{1}=1 \;or\; 2  $$

The process continues ad infinitum $\iff \nexists $ a factorization into primes for z

Suppose this process would continue ad infinitum.

Where $ j_{n}=1 \;or\; 2 \;and\; j_{n}\neq i_{n} $

$$z>a_{0j_{0}}\cdot a_{1j_{1}}\cdot a_{2j_{2}}\cdot....=\prod_{n\geq0}^{\infty}a_{nj_{n}} $$

But $$a_{nj_{n}}\geq2\; \forall\;n$$

Thus $$ z>\infty \;and\; z=\infty $$

But we took z finite thus this process must stop at some point, and thus  $\exists$ prime factorization for all positive integers

Comment: To contradict infinite chain, note that at each step the factors are integers less than the factored integer.  Because there are only a finite number of integers below the start, the chain has to stop.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3161147/242) for more pedagogical discussion on this particular inductive proof.

Answer (score 1):

You implicitly imply induction (that there is no infinite descending chain of naturals). This must be made explicit for the proof to be rigorous. Below is a  way to do so that highlights innate structure.

${\small {\bf Lemma}}\,\ \Bbb N_{>1} =$ only set $S$ of naturals $>\! 1$ containing  $\rm\color{#c00}{all\ primes}$ & $\rm\color{#0a0}{closed\,  under\, multiplication}$

**Proof** $\,\ $  If $\,n\,$ is  $\rm\color{#c00}{ prime}$ then by hypothesis $\,n\in S.\,$ Else $\,n\,$ is composite, $ $ so $\ n = j k\ $ for $\, 1 < j,k < n.\,$ By strong induction the smaller $\ j,k\in S,\,$ $\rm\color{#0a0}{hence}$ $\, n = jk\in S.$

**Corollary** $ $ Every natural $>1$ has a prime factorization.

**Proof** $ $ The set $S$ of naturals $>1$ having prime factorizations contains $\rm\color{#c00}{all\ primes}$ (each is a singleton product) and is $\rm\color{#0a0}{closed\ under\ multiplication},\,$ so the lemma yields $\,S = \Bbb N_{> 1}$.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3543271/242) for further remarks on this type of inductive proof.