# Proof by infinite descent

Tags: proof-explanation

Proof by infinite descent is used, for example, to prove the irrationality of sqrt2. But can it be used also to prove that a property holds true for an infinite set? If so, is there an example?

Comment: Infinite descent is equivalent to the [contrapositive of induction.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2948742/242), so pick any indutive proof that shows that a property holds true for all naturals and rewrite it in contrapositive descent form.

Comment: The irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ **is** a property of an infinite set: it says that the infinite set $\Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N}$ contains no member $(i, j)$ with $i^2 = 2j^2$.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you both for your answers.