# How to make Roger Penrose's proof of $\sqrt{2}$'s irrationality rigorous?

Tags: induction

Taken from pg-53 of Roger Penrose's road to reality,

Suppose $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, then:

$$ \sqrt{2} = \frac{p}{q}$$

Where $p$ and $q$ are some integers with $ q \neq 0$:

Squaring and rearrangnig:

$$ 2 q^2 = p^2$$

This means $p$ is even, and hence, $p=2p_1$, meaning that:

$$ q^2 = 2p_1^2$$

This means that $q$ is even, we can put $q=2q_1$, where $q_1$ is some integer, meaning that:

$$ 2q_1^2 = p_1^2$$

See that this looks same as the equation we begun with $2q^2 =p^2$, repeating the procedure we done it again we can further find that $p_1$ and $q_1$ is again even writing $p_1 = 2p_2$ and $q_1=2q_2$, after simplifications we will find again:

$$ 2q_2^2 = p_2^2$$

Repeating the procedure many times, we could repeat this as many times as we want , we get a recurrence for $q_i$s as:

$$q_i = 2q_{i+1}$$

Or, $$\frac{q_i}{2} = q_{i+1}$$

Obeying:

$$q>q_1>q_2...$$

Penrose writes:

"..All of these integers being positive. But any decreasing sequence of positive integers must come to an end, contradicting the fact that this sequence is unending. This provides us with a contradiction to what has been supposed , namely that there is a rational number which squares to $2$"

Firstly where was it assumed that the sequence is 'unending' and what exactly does it mean for a sequence to end? I thought sequence could go on forever..

**P.S: I understand the square root of two's irrationality proof already, the point is not to prove the statement in itself but understand this particular proof.**

Comment: Take a loook here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent

Comment: That proof looks a bit different to this @TitoEliatron

Comment: The maiin idea of both proofs is that you cannot go back infinitely many times into the positive integers. If you take a decreasing sequence of POSITYIVE integers, this sequence MUST be finite.

Comment: This is a contrapositive form of (strong) induction known as **infinite descent**, e.g. see the Remark in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2948742/242) or see [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent). The wiki page explicitly discusses this classical prototypical example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly where was it assumed that the sequence is 'unending'**

Here: $$q>q_1>q_2>\ldots$$

He means that it is an infinite *strictly decreasing* sequence: each later term less than the previous one.  This infinite sequence is constructed inductively.  He uses the ellipsis notation to suggest this.

**what exactly does it mean for a sequence to end? I thought sequence could go on forever..**

Yes, a sequence can go on forever. But an infinite sequence **of positive integers** cannot *strictly* decrease forever. That is what the [well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) says.

Compare this to the case of rational numbers, where you can have $1/2 > 1/4 > 1/8 > \ldots > 1/2^n > \ldots $ forever.

Comment: Oh right, so he is saying there is no infinitely unique terms

Comment: @Buraian Yes, the strict ordering implies all terms would have to be unique...